# Problem with CardService.newAuthorizationException()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, gmail-addons, google-apps-script-addon

I have two Gmail Add-ons with **the same code** (DEV and PROD versions). And in my code I have standard `accessProtectedResource` function (from [Add-ons documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/non-google-services#non-google_oauth_configuration_example)):

```
  function accessProtectedResource(url, data) {
  var service = getOAuthService();
  var maybeAuthorized = service.hasAccess();

  if (maybeAuthorized) {
    ...
  }

  if (!maybeAuthorized) {
    CardService.newAuthorizationException()
    .setAuthorizationUrl(service.getAuthorizationUrl())
    .setResourceDisplayName("Timelines")
    .throwException();
  }
}
```

The problem is that if user not authorized - in PROD version this function build AuthorizationCard correctly:

[image]

But in DEV, with **the same code**, the same function is crashing the add-on: 
[image]
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Does switching between `runtimeVersions` change anything?

Comment: @Cooper Wow, I changed it from "V8" to "STABLE" and it works.  Why it can be? I spent 2 days trying to solve it. **Thanks a lot for your answer!**

Comment: There are a significant number of issues related to the new version.  If you have any other problems with other scripts try that first for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is a bug!

This is a bug that has been reported before on [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker):

---

[Class AuthorizationException issue on V8](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149832151)

---

You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on this page as it lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.